# How To Process Arbitrary Number of Form Fields

Tags: forms, coldfusion, railo, cfml

I am using ColdFusion (Railo 3.3), and I have several forms using jQuery that can dynamically add a set of form fields (for instance, the user can tick a box to add another company owner that brings up all the relevant fields for the additional owner).  All the information needs to be inserted into a database, but I don't know exactly how many fields will be submitted at any given time.

How do I process this arbitrary number of fields to insert into a DB with ColdFusion?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could show us the HTML, jQuery code, DB schema, and CF code that you have so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form is a structure aka Collection.

You can just loop over the entire form structure and insert all the fields, you will probably need to exclude some like the submit button etc, but you should know the name of this.

```
<cfloop collection=#form# item="field"> 
    <cfif field neq 'submit'>
        .... insert into DB #form[field]#
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: Nice! I knew there was a simple way to do it. I assume this technique works similarly well with stored procedures?

Comment: Yes the bit of code you generate at the .... bit is unrelated it can be a stored proc etc.

Comment: So you have an insert for each form field then?

Comment: Depends what your doing, if its a single table, loop over the fields and generate a list of fields to insert rather than separate inserts.

Comment: Remember to use query params and check the data for SQL injections as inserting anything directly from POST is not a good idea